# Is there a way to check if a batch of items exist within a dynamoDB table (python sdk)?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have to periodically update the data that is stored in my DynamoDB based on changes in an external source of data. The data in this external source can contain new or updated data (which is not an issue) but it is also possible that data is deleted from the external source.

So for example, I have 20.000 items in my DynamoDB as a result of the previous extraction of data of the external source.

I query the external source of data to update my DynamoDB and receive 19.456 items from the query, this implies some data is deleted. The issue is that I don't see any way to determine which items are deleted. The only possibility I see is to retrieve all 20.000 items and check if the ID of the item exists in the items I received from the external source.

Is there a more efficient way to handle this? Or would I need to work with some external KV-store, or a simple json file that is stored in a S3 bucket that contains all the IDs?

Comment: How do you add to your DynamoDB table from your external source? What is your external source?

Comment: The external source could be any document/information management system (Sharepoint, Confluence,...). The data is initially added by connecting to the source and extracting it via the provided API. For this process, I've created specific services. So adding data is done in batch jobs that are triggered by API calls to these services. I was thinking to implement the same for an Update of the data.

Comment: You’re right, JSON diff (meh) or something like Redis should be very quick for you. I can’t think of a way to do a batch diff in DynamoDB

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB can do this efficiently at the magnitude of items you are describing. Create a GSI with a ProjectionType of KEYS_ONLY. Then scan/query the GSI to get all keys. This is likely under 5MB of data. Using the primary keys, call DeleteItem for any keys not found in your source data.